# Wrapping C++ references into a C API

Tags: c++, c, reference

I have a header file for what is supposed to be a combined C++ and C API. The C part is wrapped into `extern "C"`, but the declarations themselves look very much unlike C; for example:

```
foo::Bar& Foo_Baz_GetBarOfQux(void *_self, const foo::Qux &qux);
```

Is there a way to actually use it form plain C? I obviously cannot use this header, but maybe I can redeclare it somehow:

```
/* type? */ Foo_Baz_GetBarOfQux(void*, const /* type? */);
```

What puzzles me is how to declare types of these references (if it's possible).

P.S. I know I can write my own C wrapper on top of this: I declare the classes as opaque structures:

```
typedef struct foo_bar foo_bar_t;
typedef struct foo_baz foo_baz_t;
typedef struct foo_qux foo_qux_t;
```

and then write a C-like function that wraps the above function:

```
extern "C" 
foo_bar_t*
foo_baz_get_bar_of_qux(
    foo_baz_t* baz,
    foo_qux_t* qux)
{
    return (foo_bar_t*) Foo_Baz_GetBarOfQux(baz, *(foo::Qux*)qux);
}
```

But I wonder if I can use the original `Foo_Baz_GetBarOfQux()` directly.

Comment: AFAIK niether you have scope resolution operator `::` in C nor you can return references like `Bar&` so you cannot use the function as is in plain C

Comment: @another.anon.coward Right, but maybe I can redeclare it? (Updated the question.)

Comment: I think, it should be possible, if you define C types (structs?) with the same memory layout as foo::Bar and foo::Qux have.

Comment: @Alex I cannot do this: the C++ "classes" in the header file do not have any members, except few inline methods. And all these inline methods actually call these `Foo_Baz_GetBarOfQux()` functions, which are declared as C, but use C++ types. I suspect these are actually C functions :)

Answer (score 7):

No you cannot use `Foo_Baz_GetBar()` directly, the calls to a member function in `c++` involves implicitly passing of an `this` pointer which does not exist in your `c` code.

Comment: Well, it's my fault; I tried to prepare a simplified example and lost that pointer. I'm modifying the question.

Answer (score 2):

In general, it would be better to use opaque structures.

In the "C" interface of the code, do not ever try to pry within the opaque structure, just dutifully pass the pointers around.

In the "C++" part, you should define the structure and actually fill them appropriately (I would avoid the blind typecasting).

Of course, the "C++" part should not be exposed in the "C" header lest it confuses the C compiler.

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the only option. I cannot really fill data on the C++ side, because all I have is that header and the C++ "classes" there declare a few inline "methods" that actually call the same `Foo_Baz_GetBarOfQux()` and similar functions that have C linkage but C++ types. So far the casting-dereferencing idiom ``*(foo::Qux*)qux`` worked OK.