# C/C++ API puzzle

Tags: c++, c, reference

This is an completely rewritten version of [an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8983236/wrapping-c-references-into-a-c-api); I think the first version omitted important details; this one provides all the context.

I have a header of some C++ API. The API declares a few classes like this:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    inline void Bar(void);
    /* more inlines */
private:
    inline Foo();
    /* maybe more inline constructors */
}
```

I.e. no members, all functions are inline and public, except constructors. Constructors are private, so, as far as I understand C++, I cannot really call them. To create these objects I'm supposed to use `auto_ptr`s to them:

```
class FooAutoPtr : public std::auto_ptr<Foo> 
{
public:
    inline FooAutoPtr();
    /* one for each Foo constructors */
}
```

The API also has a second set of functions like this:

```
void Foo_Bar(void *self);
Foo* Foo_Constructor();
```

Let's call them **core functions**, because these are the symbols actually exported from the host app. Not the C++ classes.

Core functions have C linkage (i.e. they declared as `extern "C"`), but they are declared as taking and returning C++ types (e.g. they can take a reference: `Foo &foo`). Finally the header contains the implementation of the inline functions of the C++ classes. All these functions do the same: they call the core functions. For example, the `FooAutoPtr` constructor is like this:

```
inline FooAutoPtr::FooAutoPtr()
{
   reset(Foo_Constructor());
}
```

From what I understand, the code receives some object that is supposed to be a pointer to `Foo` from the host app and changes the `auto_ptr` gizmo to point to this object. But to the developer it looks as if it was a true pointer to `Foo`. And calling `Foo::Bar()` goes like this:

```
inline Foo::Bar()
{
    Foo_Bar(this);
}
```

This goes for all C++ classes and methods. Clever, huh?

Now, could somebody please explain what does all this mean? :) It's not a true C++ API, is it? To me it looks more like a thin C++ wrapper on top of a C API. If so, **can I redeclare the core functions to lose the C++ bits**? I understand how to write a C wrapper around C++ (actually, I already wrote it), but, if possible, I'd rather lose the wrapper and use the functions directly. But how do I lose the C++ stuff?

For example, there could be a function with references:

```
Bar& Foo_GetBar(void* self, const Baz& baz, int& i);
```

Right now I call it from my C++ wrapper like this:

```
typedef struct bar bar_t; /* and others */
/*...*/
bar_t*
foo_get_bar(foo_t* foo, baz_t* baz, int* i)
{
    return (bar_t*) &Foo_GetBar(foo, *(Baz*)baz, *i);
}
```

and it works (I have no idea, how). But I'd rather have it redeclared like this:

```
/* type? */ Foo_GetBar(foo_t*, /* type? /*, /* type? */);
```

**UPDATE**: I found an interesting thing that confirms [Neil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9010553/478521). It is code in Common Lisp that uses the same API. (Naturally, it has to use the C part.) And, from what I can (barely) read in the source, the author simply used pointers in place of of references. Here's a snippet from code that converts C++ declarations into Lisp:

```
;; use * instead of & - we're not interested in C++ details
line (regex-replace-all "&" line "*")
```

So that's it :) Thanks, everyone!

Comment: Wow, a question that is _legitimately_ tagged both `c` and `c++`. A rare appearance...

Comment: If the core functions return C++ types (references) then it _is_ a real live C++ API (_not_ a C API), but it's just not an object-oriented one.

Comment: @SethCarnegie So that's it :) You see, the header even has a comment near the core functions saying that these are "for C-only environment". Well, another outdated comment :)

Comment: But your function `foo_get_bar` is still compiled with C++ compiler, right?

Comment: @Krizz Yes, of course. But it exports it as "C", and all types are also C, so I can call it from plain C.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In theory, the details of how a compiler treats a reference in an C-linkage declaration is an unspecified implementation detail. However many compilers treat it as if it was a pointer. So if the C++ library header imports `Bar& Foo_GetBar(void* self, const Baz& baz, int& i);` then you could try importing it into your C header as `bar_t* Foo_GetBar(foo_t* self, const baz_t* baz, int* i);` and it might just work.

Comment: I'll give it a try. I suspected something like that, but was not too brave to start without a confirmation :) Thanks!

Comment: BTW, I updated the post about Lisp code I just found that uses the same API and yes, it simply uses pointers :) So you're right.

Answer (score 1):

```
#define & *    // convert references into pointers.
```

*Stop. Right. There.* That was a joke, rather than an attempt to see how many downvotes could be accumulated on a single answer.

But the approach of rewriting the header file to replace references with pointers should certainly work. Because these are C functions, there's no name mangling to worry about, and I've yet to see a compiler that doesn't implement references as pointers. (Is there any other possible way?)

Comment: `#define` only works for identifiers though, so you can't do that trick :)

Comment: @Seth: Indeed. Which is just as well, really.